# Reasons for using null vs empty in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, null

I wish to read a csv into a data frame:

e.g.

```
name, age, city
Dave, , London
Bob, 24, Melbourne
Joe, 38, Boston
```

I wish to keep rows where there is no age listed.

If I read empty csv values into the dataframe as NaN I can filter with is `df[‘age’].isnull()`

If I read empty csv values into the data frame as empty strings I can filter by `df[‘age’]!=“”`

I have researched to understand the difference between empty and NaN. But what is not obvious to me still is what are the implications/advantages/disadvantages of using each method or are they just two methods to achieve the same result?

Comment: ' ' does not mean that is NaN also go check `na_values` , you can pass ' ' to NaN when read the csv

Comment: What if you want to distinguish between `NaN` and `''`?

Comment: @wen yes I know I can pass '' to NaN - I am deciding whether to!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference in my mind is how the dataframe handles each value. If you read in as `NaN`, you can use built-in methods like `isna()` and `df.info` to find null values, where you can't necessarily if you just initialize with an empty string